# Preventing SQL injection in PHP with MDB2

Tags: php, postgresql, sql-injection, mdb2

I'm trying to figure out how to prevent sqlinjection, I wrote this basic function : function

```
antiInjectie($inputfromform){
    $temp = str_replace("'", "`",$inputfromform);
    $temp = str_replace("--", "~~",$temp);
    return htmlentitites($temp);
}
```

However someone told me to also take hex values in consideration, but how do I do this?

**Update**
I'm stuck with MDB2 and pgsql

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: Unfortunately I'm stick with MDB2 :(

Comment: If you aren't going to use PDO, look at the DB functions of the connection type you are using.  They usually have escape functions already wrapped.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Bobby-Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/php) has a good guide to preventing SQL injection.

In short: Don't twiddle with the input yourself, use database API methods that allow bound parameters.

Comment: Bobby tables is not a "great link."

Comment: Engaging example showing why the problem is a problem? Check. Explanations of how to deal with the problem in a variety of languages? Check. Invitation to supply improvements or report issues? Check. Seems pretty great here.

Answer (score 2):

With [MDB2](http://pear.php.net/MDB2) you can do the same as with PHP’s native [PDO abstraction](http://php.net/book.pdo) that was proposed in related question [*Best way to stop SQL Injection in PHP*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php). You can either use a prepared statement with [`prepare` and `execute`](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.mdb2.intro-execute.php) or by [quoting](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.mdb2.intro-quote.php) and inserting the values manually.

Answer (score 2):

Use [pg_query_params()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php), the most easy function to avoid SQL injection using PHP and PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 1):

First, don't write any escapting function yourself. They're very likely to be broken and the database library is very likely to contain a proper one. For mysql you can use [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

A much better longterm solution though is not to create your full query as text, but rather use prepared queries and pass the values during execution. For mysql, check the mysqli extension.