# PostgreSQL query works but not with php

Tags: postgresql, php

I want to make a php query to a PostgreSQL database. I tested the query in the server and returns, but when I try it in php:

```
<?php

//Check the input
if (!isset($_POST['variable']))
echo "Address not selected";

$input = $_POST['variable'];
//$input = ucfirst(trim($_POST['variable']));
//echo $input;


$conn = pg_connect("host=localhost port=5432 dbname=geocoder user=postgres");
if (!$conn)
echo "Could not connect to server..";

$sql = "SELECT (addy).stateabbrev FROM geocode($input);";
$result = pg_query($conn, $sql);

if  (!$result)
    echo "Query did not executed..";

?>
```

I get that "Query did not executed..";

The string for the QUERY is taken from a html page using javascript.

In the error.log of Apache2 i get:

> PHP Warning:  pg_query(): Query failed: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "Penn"\nLINE 1: SELECT (addy).stateabbrev FROM geocode(O

What can be the point here?

Comment: you should be using a placeholder in the SQL rather than interpolation, and you should be verifying/sanitizing the input.

Comment: You are experiencing a SQL injection. Learn about that now and first: http://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: possible duplicate of [Preventing SQL injection in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725520/preventing-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Using $input = pg_escape_string($_POST['variable']); didn't helped

Comment: You might want to look into adding error checking to your code.  It's real easy in php and very useful when things don't work.  Assuming you've gotten an input, assuming you've connected to the db, and assuming you got a result back are all bad form.  Check each time for an error.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments, but I founded the problem. $input must be inside single quotations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find the problem, which is the fact that $input variable from geocode() function, must be surrounded by single quotes:

```
geocode('$input')
```

:)

Answer (score 0):

Sanitize the user supplied data:

```
$input = pg_escape_literal($conn, $input);
$sql = "SELECT (addy).stateabbrev FROM geocode($input);";
```